# Why doesn't the following code not bring results? I expect to see a table containing :Book title, Book price

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

### I ran the following code and it did not return a table. Instead i got []. i have written my code as:

```
    >>> import requests
    >>> import bs4
    >>> import re
    >>> import pandas as pd
    >>> full_dict={'Title':[],'Price':[],'Availability':[]}
    >>> for index in range(1,50):
        res=requests.get("http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books_1/index?={index}.html")
        soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
        books=soup.find_all(class_='product_prod')
        for book in books:
            book_title=book.find(href=re.compile("title"))
            book_price=book.find('div',{'class':'product_price'})
            book_availability=book.find('p',{'class':'instock.availability'})
            full_dict['Title'].append(book_title)
            full_dict['Price'].append(book_price)
            full_dict['Availability'].append(book_availability)


    >>> df=pd.DataFrame(full_dict)
    >>> print(df)
```

### i expect to get a table with the book title,price and availability(whether the book is in stock or not) form the first 50 pages of this website: http://books.toscrape.com/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You have numerous errors in your code.

1. You are using `f-string` notation without an `f-string`
2. Your URL is wrong
3. The class is `product_pod` not `product_prod`
4. Your methods for finding the title, price, and availability are not right.

You can try the following:

```
import requests
import bs4
import re
import pandas as pd
full_dict={'Title':[],'Price':[],'Availability':[]}
for index in range(1,50):
    res=requests.get(f"http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books_1/page-{index}.html")
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    books=soup.find_all(class_='product_pod')
    for book in books:
        book_title=book.find(True, {'title': True}).attrs['title']
        book_price=book.find('div',{'class':'product_price'}).find('p', {'class': 'price_color'}).text
        book_availability=b.find('p',{'class':'instock availability'}).text.strip()
        full_dict['Title'].append(book_title)
        full_dict['Price'].append(book_price)
        full_dict['Availability'].append(book_availability)


df=pd.DataFrame(full_dict)
print(df)

#Remove weird A character
df['Price'] = df.Price.str.strip('Â')




                                                Title    Price Availability
0                                 A Light in the Attic  £51.77     In stock
1                                   Tipping the Velvet  £53.74     In stock
2                                           Soumission  £50.10     In stock
3                                        Sharp Objects  £47.82     In stock
4                Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind  £54.23     In stock
```